# To remove parent folder from url

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the below code i am geting a url in a string in this format:Folder/File1 or Folder/SubFolder1/File.In this i want to remove the parent folder and get the file if it has subfolders it should create a subfolder in server in that name .Pls help me to do this.

```
public void FileUpload(string sBatchName, string url)
{
     string dd=  url.TrimStart();

     string Uploadpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"];
     string ProjectName = drpBatchCreation.SelectedItem.Text;
     string strPhysicalApplicationPath = Uploadpath.TrimEnd("\\".ToCharArray()) + "\\"+ProjectName+"\\";

     strPhysicalApplicationPath = strPhysicalApplicationPath + "\\" + sBatchName + "\\Input\\" + dd;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit information about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mathew 1 In string url the url is Foldername/Filename in this case it should omit foldername in case 2 if it is folder/Subfolder/file name it should omit Folder and create a subfolder

Comment: Can you tell me whether the given path will be an absolute path(ie starting with root drive info) or relative to asp.net application(ie we need to use `MapPath`)?

Comment: @Mathew Yes it is absolute path and related to asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `Path` in the `System.IO` namespace provide this functionality.

Suppose you have the following:

```
String filePath  = "Folder/File1.txt";

//Get only 'File.txt'
String fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
```

If you want both the parent subfolder and the filename:

```
String filePath  = "Folder/SubFolder/File1.txt";

//Get 'Subfolder/File.txt'
String fileNameWithSubfolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)), Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

You can use the different methods of `Path` to achieve what you want.

Reference:
[MSDN System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx)